# choice_set confusion (Django tutorial)

Tags: django

I'm reaching the end of the first page of the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/). I tried a quick experiment, and since it hasn't worked I'm confused. Following along with the tutorial, I have a variable `p`:

```
p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Rather than creating a poll using `p.choice_set.create(choice='Not much', votes=0)` as the tutorial instructs, I tried:

```
x = Choice(choice='Not much', votes=0, poll=p)
```

Having done this I would have thought that `p.choice_set.all()` would return something more than an empty list. But it *does* return an empty list.

(However, if I try `x.poll` then I get `<Poll: What's up?>` as I would have expected, so the relationship is only working one way it seems.)

I'm sure there's a good reason why this doesn't work, even though it seems like it ought to! (please bear in mind I have no database experience)

Any thoughts welcome

Comment: have you tried saving x? x.save()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x = Choice(choice='Not much', votes=0, poll=p)` creates an instance of a `Choice` model but it is not yet saved to the database. `p.choice_set.all()` queries the database for choices which are associated with the given poll. Since `x` was not saved to the DB it will not be found.

Comment: So, if I were to actually create an instance of choice (the former method) and then save using x.save(); would it behave identically to the latter method or will there be any change?

Comment: Yes if you save the choice to the DB then it will be returned by `p.choice_set.all()`.